# Display progress as percentage

Tags: c#, int, percentage

This should be relatively simple.

**What I have:**

```
int progress; // iteration we are on, starts at 0, always incr by 1
int percentage; // from 1 - 100, starts at 0
int percentage_trip; // derived from total_results / 100
int total_results; // lets say its 200 (note that it can be anything, like 939049)
```

**What I need:**

In the above example, each time *progress* hits 2, 4, 6, 8 etc, the percentage integer should be incremented by 1 (ie, percentage++;)

My ideas have revolved around terribly formatted nested IF statements and I am looking for the proper way of doing this.

Comment: shouldn't the `percentage` be `(progress/total_results)*100`?

Comment: @Danny:  integer arithmetic would require `(progress*100/total_results)` (with hopes of not overflowing) -- what you have would always be zero until `progress >= total_results`.

Comment: I haven't though about overflow. Can we do something on division that would round or discard remainders? It does not have to be hardcore precise

Comment: No preference. Let's do what works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int incrementAmount = total_results/100;
if (progress % incrementAmount) { percentage++; }
```

Comment: Assuming total_results > 200 and isn't some ridiculously large number (or negative, which we'd assume it's not), this would work.  I'm not sure of modulus evaluation, but I'd add `== 0` in the condition statement.

If total is less than 200, you'd have to have some custom logic to avoid weird behaviour.

Comment: Typically the total_results will be something between 20,000 - 60,000

Comment: `if (progress % percentage_trip) { percentage++; }` ... why am I getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'... something obvious I am not looking at

Comment: Fixed by adding ==0 to end of if statement as Devin had suggested. Thank you!